# Reorganize files in Salesforce DX project

Tags: salesforce, sfdx

We have an existing salesforce 2GP package that follow the default directory layout with components in main/default. I would like to break that up into feature folders, but I am not able to move files for existing components and push that. When I move a file, sfdx sees that as two operations: a delete and an add operation, so it complains that "Cannot delete managed object". Files for objects that have not yet been published can be moved around freely.

Is there some way to rearrange the file layout of the files in a previously published package?

Thanks,
Morten

Answer (score 0):

1st or 2nd generation package? Your org is source tracked (you mentioned "push" rather than "deploy")? You might be able to shut the tracking up with [`sfdx force:source:legacy:tracking:reset`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_source.htm#cli_reference_force_source_legacy_tracking_reset) but it's bit nuclear option. Consider asking on dedicated https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/ too

Comment: It is a 2nd generation package. As for the source tracking: we make all changes to source files that are pushed using the cli to a scratch org during development. I'm new in the Salesforce world, so please excuse me - I haven't grasped all the different concepts yet.